# How convert query to PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can yo please tell me an example how to convert into an Stored Procedure? ( the query is muuuuch larger)
I just need an example
 how to convert C2

```
Select 
A1,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,C1,C2
From (
Select    Distinct

          A.Fiseguro,
          Trunc(A.Fdfecsurt) A1,
          'SEGURO DE MOTO'   B1,
          'Q'                B2,  
          A.Fnprima          B3,
          A.Fccertificado    B4,
          To_Number(
            Sms.Fnsumaaseg
          )                  B5,
          'FISICA'           C1,
          Replace( Coalesce(
            Case When Regexp_Like(Trim(Substr(Sia.Saz_Adnrow, 25, 14)), '^\d') And Length(Trim(Substr(Sia.Saz_Adnrow, 25, 14)))<13 Then Trim(Substr(Sia.Saz_Adnrow, 25, 14)) Else Null End,
              Case When Regexp_Like(Trim(Mc.Fcrfc), '^\d') And Length(Trim(Mc.Fcrfc))<13 Then Trim(Mc.Fcrfc) Else Null End,
              Case When Regexp_Like(Trim(Sds2.Fcdocnumref), '^\d') And Length(Trim(Sds2.Fcdocnumref))<13 Then Trim(Sds2.Fcdocnumref) Else Null End,
              Case When Regexp_Like(Trim(Scl1.Fcdni), '^\d') And Length(Trim(Scl1.Fcdni))<13 Then Scl1.Fcdni Else Null End,
              Case When Regexp_Like(Trim(Scl1.Fcdocnumref), '^\d') And Length(Trim(Scl1.Fcdocnumref))<13 Then Trim(Scl1.Fcdocnumref) Else Null End,
              Case When Regexp_Like(Trim(Scl2.Fcrfc), '^\d') And Length(Trim(Scl2.Fcrfc))<13 Then Trim(Scl2.Fcrfc) Else Null End,
              Case When Regexp_Like(Trim(Scl2.Fcdn2), '^\d') And Length(Trim(Scl2.Fcdn2))<13 Then Trim(Scl2.Fcdn2) Else Null End,
              Case When Regexp_Like(Trim(Scl2.Fcdpi), '^\d') And Length(Trim(Scl2.Fcdpi))<13 Then Trim(Scl2.Fcdpi) Else Null End,
              'CF'
          ), '-')            C2,

From table A
  Left Join table Sms
        On Sms.Fipais = To_Char(A.Fipais)
        And Sms.Ficanal = To_Char(A.Ficanal)
        And Sms.Fisucursal = To_Char(A.Fisucursal)
        And Sms.Finopedido = To_Char(A.Finopedido)
```

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. What do you mean by converting to a stored procedure? Do you want to call the stored procedure and get something as a result? What would you want to pass to the stored procedure and what do you want back? Is it ensured only one value is the result or do you need an array of data back? Please be more specific.

Comment: Ye I want the get the same resultset the query brings me.. but in a SP instead

Comment: Are you saying, then, that you want a stored procedure that takes no input parameters and has a `SYS_REFCURSOR` as an output parameter that is opened for this query?  That would be an odd construct.  A view would be more conventional.  If you need a PL/SQL block rather than a SQL construct, a function that returned a `SYS_REFCURSOR` would generally be more appropriate.

Comment: Don't use PL/SQL for anything you can do simply in SQL.

Comment: I just want to know how  to output 'n' field on 'N' tables applaying some validtaioms on them before

Answer (score 2):

This will not quite answer your question but if your query is

```
SELECT x FROM t WHERE ID = 1;
```

Then the stored procedure returning x (assuming ID is a unique index):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_STORED_PROC(i_id number)
RETURN x.t%TYPE
IS
  l_val x.t%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT x
  INTO   l_val
  FORM   t
  WHERE  ID = i_id;
  return l_val;
END;
```